# MD1000 + PERC 5/E SATA III support? Interposer on sata?

Tags: dell, dell-perc, dell-powervault

Does Dell MD1000 + perc5/e support SATA 3 HDDs? Will I need interposer for my tray/caddy to support sata II/III hdds?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that it's required, but I support a number of MD1000's attached to PERC 5/e controllers that have SATA-III disks connected and we did use trays with interposers. We saw differing reports of SATA disks working in the MD1000 w/ and w/o interposers so we opted to play it safe and just ordered the interposers. The disks have been working well for us.

Comment: Thanks, but the price for the interposer is really big, isnt it better to buy SAS drives instead? They don't need interposer if Im not mistaken.

Comment: The configuration we needed-- fifteen 3TB drives in JBOD-- wasn't possible w/ SAS disks. We used the MD's because we liked the build quality of the Dell (LSI) hardware and could get several of the units dirt-cheap (off lease).

Comment: So with SATA you can put 3TB drives? I thought that only 2TB drives are supported.

Comment: No-- you're right. I just checked. They're 2TB. I don't know what I was thinking. We wanted a lot of JBOD cheap, but in a decent quality enclosure w/ redundant power and controllers. That's why we picked the MD.

Answer (score 1):

in my experience (I was was working at dell at the peak of md1000 usage) some disks required interposers and some didn't. Physically the connector is the same. I suggest you simply get in touch with Dell, provide your service tags and ask this question there.

Comment: It sounds like the OP is talking about using non-Dell disks in the MD. I doubt Dell is going to answer any questions about that.

Comment: nope, non-dell disks are totally NSGA, and for a good reason

Comment: National Sporting Goods Association?

Comment: "not supported go away" :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think Dell will reject my question, but I will try.